# MS Word flips the document orientation when exporting to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I am experiencing a weird problem with MS Word. It is flipping my documents when I am exporting to PDF: I get a landscape mode PDF if my Word document is in portrait mode; and vice-versa.

I have Word 16 for Mac. I have already tried to do a fresh install of MS and, quite incredibly, the problem remains. The problem is also happening if I use an online Word to PDF converter, which really confuses me.

If that can help, I believe the problem first happened after I connected my Mac to my printer.

Comment: My problem was "solved" after I deleted the printer (a physical one) from my Mac. Not sure if I should delete my post, I guess I'll leave it if someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To let others with this issue know: I've had the same issue and it was solved by deleting the printer from the Mac (like francoiskroll did).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The general procedure below is for Windows,
but you might find some parallel procedure for the Mac.
But I can't help further with the Mac (don't have one).

1. Go to Start -> Devices and Printers
2. Right-click your printer and select "Printing preferences"
3. Select the "Layout" tab and set the Orientation to "Landscape"
4. Click "OK" button

Answer (score -1):

My problem was "solved" (definitely not the ideal solution) after I deleted the printer (a physical one) from my Mac.

Not sure if I should delete my post, I guess I'll leave it here if someone has the same problem.